# Neo4j.rb WARNING: The constraint option is no longer supported?

Tags: neo4j.rb

How to fix this warning (WARNING: The constraint option is no longer supported (Defined on StayPal for user_id)
I am using
Neo4j.rb > 8
neo4j > 3
Following

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/ActiveNode.html

```
using property :user_id, constraint: :unique
```

How to add uniqness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining constraints on models for auto-creation isn’t supported as of 8.0 of the neo4j gem. See this section of the upgrade guide: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/UpgradeGuide.html#indexes-and-constraints